# Why do we need BCP Node in AOAGs

Tags: availability-groups, disaster-recovery

I have PROD Site and DR Site. If PROD site is completely down.I have backups of PROD site for Databases which are in SYNC and backups using a Third party tool.So I have copied the latest backups to DR Site and I can restore them.If I have fresh DB copies and if I am able to bring the server online by restoring latest backups ,what exactly is the use of DR BCP server ?

Answer (score 2):

How quickly can you get the databases restored from backups as compared to failing over to the DR replica? Failing over to the DR replica can be done without data loss, provided the primary replica is still accessible, and can be done in just a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to AOAGs and stuck up with few questions.Thanks for your time and response @Tara